# Android. How to Get context from different activity

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, google-cloud-messaging

I'm playing with the GCM.

Everything is perfect using the example on https://code.google.com/p/gcm/source/checkout
Im getting notifications on my app with the gcm messages,

Now I want to add the message in a listView located on my MainActivity.

Im receiving my messages on a different class (GcmIntentService.java). How can I get MainActivity context to sendBroadcast.

Already tried with

```
private static Context mContext;

public static Context getContext() {
    return mContext;
}

public static void setContext(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
}
```

But is not working.

Any Ideas.

Thanks

Comment: pass the context to the constructor of the class and use the same

Comment: @Raghunandan, how could I pass the context to the constructor?

Comment: why do you need to pass the context of main activity aroud?

Comment: @blackbelt, I want to populate a listview from a different class

Comment: @carlosh12 to which different class coz if your using activity context outside the lifecycle of the activity you might run into leaks. Do not keep long-lived references to a context-activity (a reference to an activity should have the same life cycle as the activity itself). http://www.curious-creature.org/2008/12/18/avoid-memory-leaks-on-android/

Comment: @carlosh12 you want to update a listview which is MainActivity from a different activity?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not sure what you are doing. But keeping the below in mind

Do not keep long-lived references to a context-activity (a reference to an activity should have the same life cycle as the activity itself). 
http://www.curious-creature.org/2008/12/18/avoid-memory-leaks-on-android/

You can do as below

Example:

```
 new MyClass(ActivityName.this);

class MyClass
{
      Context mContext; 
      public MyClass(Context context)
      {
          mContext=context;
      } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

pass the context variable through constructor .

Comment: How can I pass the context through constructor?

Comment: the explanation in above comments are good please follow those which are commented by Raghunandan same thing will be in my comment but he has better explanation

Answer (score 0):

create new activity like below

```
public class GetContext extends AppCompatActivity {

Context mainActivity;

public GetContext(Context mainActivity){
    this.mainActivity = mainActivity;
}
```

and in your previous mainActivity send this context as below

```
GetContext sendContext = new GetContext(mainActivityContext);
```

where `mainActivityContext` is `Context mainActivityContext = this;`
or simply pass this instead of mainActivityContext

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_get_attendance_from_database);
}
```